# Dynamically create modules in a library

Tags: python

I have a library (`foo`) with a number of modules (`foo.bar`, `foo.baz`) that consist of a lot of overlapping boiler plate code and only some different content that can be defined statically. So I was wondering what would be the most elegant way to create these modules dynamically (and where), using as input a few attributes I would like to set (e.g. `__all__`), as well as the `__getattr__` function that I would like to overwrite.

When I search for creating modules dynamically in Python, I seem to only get results about importing modules dynamically. I would like to create these modules in such a way that users can then use e.g. `from foo.bar import quuz`.

Comment: Can  you provide an example? The boilerplate is probably easy to deal with (likely by putting it in `foo/__init__.py`), and the rest can be done specifically in `bar.py` and `baz.py`.

Comment: It seems like you're reaching for a solution to a problem that has gone somewhat down the wrong path already. Add (much) more context to your problem and dynamic modules will almost certainly end up not being the best approach.

Comment: @chepner the boilerplate is just to define `__all__` and a few other attributes and `__getattr__`. My question is how to create the modules `foo.bar` and `foo.baz` without creating the files `bar.py` and `baz.py`.

Comment: @Reinderien The purpose of these modules is to present a stable api, the classes and functions are defined in subpackages. You may not like this design, and I haven't decided yet whether i actually want to go ahead and define these modules dynamically, but i was curious how one would go about doing it, and the question could be useful for other users.

Comment: You can define modules manually (`from types import ModuleType; bar = ModuleType('bar')`). Supporting `from foo.bar import quuz` is trickier.

Comment: I think you might have to dig into the import protocol and define a custom finder and/or loader. See the `importlib` documentation for details. Making a module a package is just a matter of defining its `__path__` attribute. This is typically a list of files, though; I don't know what you would put on it if the modules are defined in `foo.py` itself, rather than in separate files.

Comment: I just started reading a [long blog post](https://tenthousandmeters.com/blog/python-behind-the-scenes-11-how-the-python-import-system-works/) on how `import` works this morning; I haven't finished it yet, but I think it will make a good companion to the `importlib` docs.

Comment: All this said, I'm not sure a single file is going to be more elegant than a directory with multiple files in it.

Comment: @chepner My reasoning is that I'm writing the same code in each of these files, which would be easier to maintain if it only existed in one place. I think conceptually and ideally, I'd like to have separate files, but somehow subclass `ModuleType` and handle the boilerplate code at the module class level.

Comment: You don't have to define all the modules in a single file to do that. Put the common code in one module, and import that module from the others. (Or consider whether you need multiple modules at all and use classes for encapsulation.)